# xcode running app in simulator throws : "iOS Simulator failed to install the application" error

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Copied xcode application from friend and created a Single View Application. While trying to build and run the application, build succeeds while Xcode is throwing me : "iOS Simulator failed to install the application" error.

I have tried several suggestions including: 
1) Reset content and Settings from ios Simulator. 
2) change deployment target.
2) Close and restart Xcode
3) open ios simulator, click home key and delete any application. 
4) deleted 5.0.1 xcode and installed 5.0.2 by copying from a friend.

current version of ios simulator: 7.0

Still getting "iOS Simulator failed to install the application" error. Is there any solution?

Comment: Which iOS Version is your project for?

Comment: @Jens, Dont have a preference at present.Tried development target for 7.0, 6.0, 6.1 and non works.